# Programar notificaciones en función de valores almacenados en BD

Tags: python, notificaciones

Muy buenas,

Os cuento la idea que tengo en mente a ver si me pueden ayudar.

Tengo un script que va recopilando datos de una web que tiene personajes: nombre, tipo, nivel, rango, etc.

La BD se va actualizando cada minuto por si hay cambios.

Por otro lado quiero realizar un modo de notificación. Cada usuario podrá elegir si un personaje está entre uno o dos valores (precio) o/y tiene un rango concreto o/y tiene un nivel o está entre varios niveles.

El problema lo tengo a la hora de plantear cómo hacer el tema de las notificaciones.
En un principio había pensado utilizar Cron en Linux. Para un par de usuarios esta bien pero si son, por ejemplo, 1000, no puedo (ni es viable) tener 1000 líneas en el Cro.
¿Como puedo hacer para buscar lo que el usuario pide cada X minutos en la BD sin usar Cron para luego notificarle?
Por ej un usuario quiere saber cada 5 minutos si hay un personaje de nombre Pepe con nivel 5 o menos y que cueste entre 100$ y 200$ ?

Todo esto lo estoy programando en Python y avisaría por Telegram (esto ya lo tengo controlado), pero desconozco cómo hacer el tema de las notificaciones por cada usuario que así lo configure.

¿Alguna idea?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Un saludo!!

Comment: esto.. esta basado en opiniones, no?

Comment: @gbianchi totalmente :/

Comment: Por favor lee [ask]. Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, trata de [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/502432/edit) tu pregunta para hacerla encajar en el formato del sitio

Comment: Perdonad si no lo hice bien o es más opinión que código como tal. En tal caso, ¿dónde podría preguntar esto? Gracias!

Comment: En el [chat] :D